# HTML Control in Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional

Tags: windows-mobile, browser, ie-mobile

I have an application which hosts the WebBrowser control; it runs fine on WM5 and WM6.  On my WM6.1 Professional device, I seem to not be able to control HTML elements with CSS.  A page rendered in IEMobile does not behave the same in the control on the 6.1Pro device.  On WM6 and 5, things are fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this Internet Explorer “6” Mobile you're talkin about? (Real version number IEMobile 8; included in WinMo 6.1.4 upwards.) It's very different to the previous IEMobiles included in earlier 6.1 releases.

Comment: The device is Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional, Build 20963.1.5.2.  It's as if the control has a minimum font size (8?) and won't let me go below that.  But the same file in IEMobile scales fonts down as far as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a lot by reading this thread.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/4d3c837d-16f4-4ae4-acc2-96bb8d573111/

For me, I added the line HI_RES_AWARE CEUX {1} to my .RC file.  So now my control runs in "high resolution," and I can make text scale down to where I need it to be.  Crazy.